# breakpoints with {withStyles} from '@material-ui /styles'

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to use breakpoints with {withStyles} from "@material-ui/styles", but the debugger shows that theme.breakpoints is not defined.

I tried to wrap the component with ThemeProvider but it does not work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-shgh7?from-embed

Answer (score 0):

withStyles exported with @material-ui/styles not provide theme props, you'll use import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

[Exemplo no code sand box arrumado ai](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-djt2x?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

```
  class app extends Component{

    render(){
       const {classes} = this.props
       return (
         <div className={classes.root}></div>
       )
    }
   }

const style = theme => ({
  root: {
   [theme.breakpoints.up('sm'){    //only show on mobile or small screen 
    display: 'none'
    },
  }
})

export default withStyles(style)(app)
```